# JSON response body not being received from OkHttp Callback

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, okhttp

I am trying to query an API to get the JSON response and store the response in an ArrayList.

This ArrayList will be later used for setting up a RecyclerView.

I am getting the response if I Log in the **OnResponse()** method from OkHttp. But when I am receiving the response in my Fragment as a String via the return in the **OkhttpHandler** then the string value is being received as null

Here's the code

**OkHttpHelper.Java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.utils;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */


public class OkHttpHandler {

    private String queryUrl;
    private String jsonData;

    private static final String TAG = "CustomTAG1";



   public OkHttpHandler(String Url) {
        this.queryUrl = Url;
    }

    public String fetchData() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(queryUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    jsonData = response.body().string();

                }
            }
        });

        return jsonData; //Even this is null when I check via Debugger
    }
}
```

**PopularMoviesFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.API;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.OkHttpHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class PopularMoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomTAG";
    private ArrayList<Movie> mMovies;

    private String jsonResponse;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mMovies=new ArrayList<>();

        String url= API.BASE_URL+API.API_KEY+API.SORT_POPULARITY;

        OkHttpHandler handler= new OkHttpHandler(url);
        jsonResponse=handler.fetchData();

        try {
           mMovies= parseItems(jsonResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Exception caught: ",e);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    private ArrayList<Movie> parseItems( String jsonResponse) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject jsonData= new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray moviesJSONArray= jsonData.getJSONArray("results");
        ArrayList<Movie> Movies= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <moviesJSONArray.length() ; i++) {

            Movie movie= new Movie();
            JSONObject movieJson= moviesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            movie.setId(movieJson.getInt("id"));
            Log.v(TAG,"TITLE IS "+movieJson.getString("title"));
            movie.setOriginalTitle(movieJson.getString("original_title"));
            movie.setOverview(movieJson.getString("overview"));
            movie.setPosterPath(movieJson.getString("poster_path"));
            movie.setVoteAverage((float) movieJson.getDouble("vote_average"));
            movie.setTitle(movieJson.getString("title"));

            Movies.add(movie);
        }

        return  Movies;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_movies,container,false);
        return view;
    }



}
```

**API.java** for building the url

```
package com.execube.genesis.utils;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class API {


    public static String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
    public static String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    public static String API_KEY = "api_key=a98debe57ccd9b42fe6b99b9014c80e3";
    public static String SORT_POPULARITY = "&sort_by=popularity.desc";
    public static String SORT_R_RATED = "&certification_country=US&certification=R&sort_by=vote_average.desc&vote_count.gte=250";
    public static String IMAGE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
    public static String IMAGE_SIZE_185 = "w500";
   }
```

Here's the URL that I am querying    http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=a98debe57ccd9b42fe6b99b9014c80e3&sort_by=popularity.desc

Answer (score 0):

`Call#enqueue` is OkHttp's asynchronous API. This means the request will be handled on a background thread and the calling thread will continue to run with OR without running the callback.

To use the data you either need to use some form of `Future` (Guava's ListenableFuture or RxJava might work) to respond to the *eventual* availability of the data or use `Call#execute()` instead of `Call#enqueue` to do the call in a synchronous way.

Comment: The data is successfully being fetched, It appears on the log but  String  jsonData = response.body().string(); is somehow always null. jsonData should have the response in the string format since it was successfully logged. Shouldn't it?

Comment: No it shouldnt. You've got the idea that the code gets executed in the order you defined it in. Since `Call#enqueue` is asynchronous the `Callback` call may be executed at any point in the future. `String jsonData = response.body().string(); ` simply hasn't been executed at the point where you do `return jsonData;`

Comment: Well could you please tell me what would be a possible work around to send the response body to the calling activity?

Comment: Doing `call.execute()` will give you the same `Response` that would be given in `onResponse()`. So getting the body would be `call.execute().body().string()`

Comment: The thing is, there are 3 Fragments which share this common code, I pass the urls to the constructors to do the network call and all of the networking is done in the fetchData()  method. Also to make the code syncronous i'll have to move it to an async task. Is there any way in which the data could be retrieved from the enqueue method?

Comment: No, because the way the code is currently structured can only be synchronous since you expect the answer to be immediately returned.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you're accessing the variable jsonData before the network operation can finish and put something in it.
Which is very unlikely to happen.

Use something like an Event Bus (I like Green Robot's), and post an event when the jsonData has something, right after the line `jsonData = response.body().string();`

And listen to this event in your UI fragment, and populate data once you receive this event.

Till then, keep showing the progress dialog/UI.

This way your code will remain async and you'll get this done as well